# Can I make tiles of a raster in postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

I am doing some work on dtms in postgis. To import the dtm, I snipped it into tiles and the work directly on the dtm works fine. Then I calculated aspect and slope of the dtm and got some bad artifacts along the tile borders, so to have this done correctly, I had to use st_union to put the tiles together before doing the calculations. So far, so good, but then I have large raster maps of slope and aspect, and when I then overlay points on those rasters, things goes very slowly (I have a point data set of a few million points). When I did the overlay on the original tiled dtm, it took about 20 minutes, when I do the same on the combined raster, it took at least one hour. Is it possible somehow to cut the calculated rasters into tiles (without exporting and re-importing them) or can I add some kind of index on those rasters that makes the overlay run faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MortenSickel - take a look at ST_Tile.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_Tile.html

Comment: Facepalm - why didn't I find that one... Thanks!